# SSH Not Working After Installing DD-WRT

Tags: ssh, router, dd-wrt

I have a pogoplug server hacked with the instructions [here](http://lifehacker.com/5637092/turn-a-pogoplug-into-a-fully+featured-linux-web-server). It has worked fine for over a year now. I can ssh into it and do what ever I want.

Today I installed DD-WRT on my router, after setting up my wireless settings again almost everything works fine.

The one problem is sshing into my pogoplug.

Whenever I try to ssh into it, I get this error.

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

After a few searches, the genrel answer is that my ip must be blocked in the servers `/etc/hosts.deny` file.

The problem is, ssh is my only means of access to the server, so how can I debug it with no access?

Comment: Try connecting with a different IP.  If you haven't already, try power-cycling the device.  Past that, pull the flash drive or drive with the root+boot filesystem from the pogoplug, and mount it on another computer and see if you find any issues in the logs.

Comment: I restarted it before I asked this question, but then the after the breaker that feed my office trips and was reset the server works fine. Nothing like random power outages to fix your computer issues :)